# SpriteKit strange touch coordinates behavior

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Touch coordinates in SpriteKit seem to have strange negative offset on Y axis.

This is how I get touch locations in my scene:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    NSLog(@"Touch location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));
}
```

If you touch the very bottom of the screen, the lowest Y coordinate value you can get is something about 8.5 points and on the top of the screen there is a noticeable area that produces identical max Y coordinate values.

Has anybody encountered the same problem? Is it a bug in SpriteKit or am I doing something wrong?

I have uploaded a demo project on GitHub to illustrate the issue: https://github.com/mirmanov/SKTouchDemo

**NOTE:** You can reproduce this behavior only on a real device. On iOS simulator everything seems to work properly.

Comment: check scene's scaleMode and try different ones

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I have played with that property already, no results.

Comment: Is this the 'invisible' Status bar or a gesture recogniser recognition area playing havoc?